# pandas get dummies for column with list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input:-

```
empNo         name    

1234         [ AB, DE ] 
5678         [ FG, IJ ]
```

Command:-

```
dataFrame = dataFrame.join(dataFrame.name.str.join('|').str.get_dummies().add_prefix('dummy_name_'))
```

The above command brings  dummy "for each character of the column name"

Output:-

```
empNo         name              dummy_name_A        dummy_name_B     dummy_name_D     dummy_name_E  dummy_name_F    dummy_name_G    dummy_name_I    dummy_name_J

1234         [ AB, DE ]             1                   1               1                   1           0               0               0               0
5678         [ FG, IJ ]             0                   0               0                   0           1               1               1               1
```

Expected:-

```
empNo         name              dummy_name_AB       dummy_name_DE    dummy_name_FG  dummy_name_IJ   

1234         [ AB, DE ]             1                   1                   0               0               
5678         [ FG, IJ ]             0                   0                   1               1
```

Comment: Strange. Can you share your dataframe like this: `print(dataFrame.to_dict())` and post result here.

Comment: If it is huge then use: `print(dataFrame.head(2).to_dict())` to limit it to two rows.

Comment: I got the issue Anton. Had accidentally converted the datatype of the column to [ .astype(str) ]. 

I removed it and my earlier command works fine as you had correctly pointed out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the list is not the list , so we using ast to convert the string type column back to list

```
import ast

df.name=df.name.apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Then using str `get_dummies`

```
s=df.name.apply(pd.Series).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).add_prefix('dummy_name_')
s
   dummy_name_AB  dummy_name_DE  dummy_name_FG  dummy_name_IJ
0              1              1              0              0
1              0              0              1              1
```

Then

```
pd.concat([df[['empNo']],s],axis=1)
```

The data input

```
df.to_dict()
{'empNo': {0: 1234, 1: 5678}, 'name': {0: ['AB', 'DE'], 1: ['FG', 'IJ']}}
```

Comment: Thanks W-B. 

This command brings the output as 

dummy_name_['AB'] , dummy_name_['DE'] , dummy_name_[ 'AB','DE' ], 
dummy_name_['FG'] , dummy_name_['IJ'] , dummy_name_[ 'FG','IJ' ], 

and one more additional column for an empty list dummy_name_[] 

Can you please help achieving the expected result given above ?

Comment: @Jenny please check above data input to see the different between mine and yours

Comment: I got the issue W-B. Had accidentally converted the datatype of the column to [ .astype(str) ]. I removed it and my earlier command works fine as you had correctly pointed out. 
Thanks for the help.